# Django/Python. QuerySet data converted in objects list converts str/int values in Tuple

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have very strange problem in very simply operation.

models.py

```
NbProducts(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    cluster = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    target_market = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    cpu_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    base_platform = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    gpu_list = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    screen_size = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    screen_resulution_list = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    touchscreen = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
    list_Products = NbProducts.objects.\
                    filter(id__in=products_for_execute).\
                    values('brand', 'name', 'id')
# list_Products:
#<QuerySet [{'brand': 'Acer', 'name': 'Aspire R7-372T', 'id': 2713}, 
#{'brand': 'Acer', 'name': 'Aspire S7-393', 'id': 2716}, 
#{'brand': 'Acer', 'name': 'Swift SF514-51', 'id': 2743},....

    class FProducts(object):
        def __init__(self, id, brand, name):

            self.id = str(id),
            self.brand = str(brand),
            self.name = str(name)

           print(self.id, self.brand, self.name)
    
    fproducts = list()
    for i in list(list_Products):
        fproducts.append(FProducts(id=i['id'], brand=i['brand'], name=i['name']))

>> {'2713',) ('Acer',) 'Aspire R7-372T'
>> {'2716',) ('Acer',) 'Aspire S7-393'
>> {'2743',) ('Acer',) 'Swift SF514-51'
```

So. Without any commands it put two of argements - 'id' & 'brand' to Tuple. argument 'Name' - all right, just string.

I don`t need Tuple. And I don`t understend what`s matter.

Additionaly i put in **init** this.

```
  self.id = self.id[0]
  self.brand = self.brand[0]
```

Ok, it helped, app is work.

But I can`t see the source of the problem.

Does it the proplem of Python (3.7) or Django (2.1.7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have create a tuple yourself here:

```
        self.id = str(id),
        self.brand = str(brand),
        self.name = str(name)
```

should be:

```
        self.id = str(id)
        self.brand = str(brand)
        self.name = str(name)
```

Comment: Ohhh... Let kill myselth. Rgds